# Trying to Implement shared preferences with a listview

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I'm getting a null pointer exception for my listview... I am trying to use shared preferences to keep the values in my listview when I come back to it

Apologies if its a silly question but from my view everything is initialised and nothing is empty that shouldnt be, so it would be great if someone else could spot the issue :{)

```
    public class MainActivity3 extends MainActivity{

    EditText display;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Button addButton;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    LoadPreferences();


    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (display.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        }

        else {
            String task = display.getText().toString();


            adapter.add(task);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            SavePreferences("LISTS", task);
        }
    }
    });
    }


protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();


}

protected void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String dataSet = data.getString("LISTS", "None Available");

    adapter.add(dataSet);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Apologies if its a silly question but from my view everything is initialised and nothing is empty that shouldnt be, so it would be great if someone else could spot the issue :{)

```
     <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="359dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText6" />
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure that in activity_main.xml is a listview with the id listView2?

Comment: A good first step would be to go to the line where where NPE happens. This line number will be shown in logcat next to your exception. There are many possibilities for NPE, and knowing where it occurs would point you in the right direction. It would also be nice if your code was formatted properly...

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.pp.application.MainActivity3.onCreate(MainActivity3.java:41)

Comment: Yes leiter0499 there a listview with that id

Comment: the line I am brought to following that error is lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: lv is null. Add activity_main.xml to your question. How is MainActivity declared?

Comment: <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="359dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button21"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText6" />  there certainly is a listview with the id in question, it seems it wont let me attach the entire xml to my question as 'i have too much code'

Comment: You can edit your question post for more (nicer formatted) code ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you put here your layout code?? Because the name of your components are not so good, So, maybe, you can be calling to another listView in another layout.

Could you try to delete your import line when you have android.R ? and then, import the correct.

If this doesn't work, up the code of layout, please :)

I am thinking about another solution. Go to listView and give it this id:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

then, Go to MainActivity and write this:

```
public class YourClass extends ListActivity
```

So, to access to listView, you just have to use the next method:

```
getListView();
```

if you want to know more, see the oficial doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

I hope It work